# Noun clause structure "student enrolling"

Tags: grammar, clauses

> There was not as many students enrolled in A as in B

Is this sentence correct?

Why it is "students enrolled", not "students enrolling"?

Comment: Just a small point. The word 'students' is plural so the example sentence should be "There _were_ not as many students enrolled in A as in B"

Comment: Student enrolling; it is not a clause, but a phrase.  We need to understand how a clause differs from phrase.

Answer (score 1):

The use depends on the point in time that the statement is made - *during* or *after* the enrollment period.

In the case that you give, one would infer that the class, or course, was already under way and the students had already *enrolled*.

If the sign up period for the class was still active, then one would use *enrolling*.

Answer (score 1):

(1) equals to (1a) in meaning, whereas (2) equals to (2a) in meaning.

> (1) *There were not as many students **enrolled** in A as in B.*
>
> (1a) *Not as many students were **enrolled** in A as in B.*
>
> (2) *There were not as many students **enrolling** in A as in B.*
>
> (2a) *Not as many students were **enrolling** in A as in B.*

Comment: Students were enrolling, or students were enrolled?  Need to review what is correct.